# How do I delete datalist entries?

Tags: html, html-datalist

I'm trying to delete datalists from a textbox so the ones I have in my HTML can appear. Is there a way to delete datalist rows?

```
<form>
            <input class="URL_Textbox" id="WebsiteName" name="WebsiteURL_Name" placeholder="URL Of Website">
            <input
                    type="button"
                    class="submit_button"
                    onClick="submitURL()"
                    value="Go"
                    list="Recommended_URLs">

            <datalist id="Recommended_URLs">
                <option value="https://www.google.com/" label="Google">
                <option value="http://www.youtube.com/" label="Youtube">
                <option value="http://www.amazon.com/" label="Amazon">
                <option value="https://www.facebook.com/" label="Facebook">
                <option value="http://reddit.com/" label="Reddit">
            </datalist>

            >
            <br>
            <input class="URL_Textbox2" id="GoogleSearchInput" name="GoogleSearch" placeholder="Search Google" required >
            <input
                    type="button"
                    class="submit_button2"
                    onClick="submitGoogle()"
                    value="Google It!"
                    >
        </form>
```

Thanks for taking the time to read and answer my question!